# Migrating T-SQL script to Snowflake - error invalid identifier

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am currently trying to migrate a T-SQL script to Snowflake.

This is the T-SQL script:

```
SELECT  
    * —- a bunch of stuff
FROM
    TABLE_DATE D
LEFT JOIN 
    TABLE_CONST AS CONST ON CODE = 999
                         AND D.DATE BETWEEN CONST.STARTDATE AND ISNULL (CONST.ENDDATE, EOMONTH(GET_DATE()))
LEFT JOIN 
    TABLE_INFO M ON CONST.CODE = M.CODE
OUTER APPLY 
    (SELECT TOP 1 *
     FROM TABLE_A 
     WHERE SECID = CONST.SECID
       AND DATE_ <= D.DATE_
     ORDER BY DATE_ DESC) SEC
OUTER APPLY 
    (SELECT TOP 1 *
     FROM TABLE_B 
     WHERE I_CODE = SEC.I_CODE 
       AND DATE_ <= D.DATE_
     ORDER BY DATE_ DESC) XR
LEFT JOIN 
    TABLE_I I ON CONST.SECID = I.SECID
WHERE 
    D.DATE_ BETWEEN CAST(‘1800-01-01’ AS DATE AND GETDATE()
```

I have converted a few parts of the script to the snowflake syntax (isnull, eomonth, outer apply) but is still facing some error.

Converted script

```
SELECT * —- a bunch of stuff
FROM TABLE_DATE D
LEFT JOIN TABLE_CONST AS CONST
ON CODE = 999
AND D.DATE BETWEEN CONST.STARTDATE AND COALESCE (CONST.ENDDATE,LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE()))

LEFT JOIN TABLE_INFO M ON CONST.CODE = M.CODE

LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM TABLE_A 
WHERE SECID = CONST.SECID
AND DATE_ <= D.DATE_
ORDER BY DATE_ DESC
) SEC

LEFT JOIN 
( SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM TABLE_B 
WHERE I_CODE = SEC.I_CODE 
AND DATE_ <= D.DATE_
ORDER BY DATE_ DESC
) XR

LEFT JOIN TABLE_I I ON CONST.SECID = I.SECID

WHERE D.DATE_ BETWEEN CAST(‘1800-01-01’ AS DATE AND CURRENT_DATE()
```

Error that I’m getting is

```
Invalid identifier ‘CONST.SECID’
```

I’m new to snowflake and sql and would really appreciate any help.

*script has been change for confidentiality purposes and it is also not possible for me to provide sample data)

Comment: What was wrong with the answer provided yesterday, and why did you delete that question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72040911/convert-sql-script-to-snowflake-script-invalid-identifier-error/72041222?noredirect=1#comment127296382_72041222

Comment: Apologies for that and thanks again for the answer but the answer didn’t work in my context because I have another join statement after the line that was giving me the error. hence I thought I should give the full code, more details and context to the question. Really apologies for that.

Comment: The Sql server APPLY feature is the snowflake [LATERAL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/join-lateral.html)

Comment: I can understand that, when I spend 20 minute explain stuff and fixing your SQL and then making you toy data and SQL work, it very obvious it not going to work for you in your real code, but deleting all that effort. It's quote offensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create or replace table TABLE_DATE(DATE_ date);
create or replace table TABLE_CONST(STARTDATE date, ENDDATE date, code number, SECID number);
create or replace table TABLE_INFO(code number);
create or replace table TABLE_A(SECID number, I_CODE number);
create or replace table TABLE_B(date_ date, I_CODE number);
create or replace table TABLE_I(SECID number);

SELECT *
FROM TABLE_DATE AS D
LEFT JOIN TABLE_CONST AS CONST
    ON CODE = 999
    AND D.DATE_ BETWEEN CONST.STARTDATE AND COALESCE(CONST.ENDDATE,LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE()))
LEFT JOIN TABLE_INFO AS M 
    ON CONST.CODE = M.CODE
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM TABLE_A 
    WHERE SECID = CONST.SECID
    AND DATE_ <= D.DATE_
    ORDER BY DATE_ DESC
) AS SEC
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM TABLE_B AS B 
    WHERE b.I_CODE = SEC.I_CODE 
    AND b.DATE_ <= D.DATE_
    ORDER BY b.DATE_ DESC
) XR
LEFT JOIN TABLE_I I ON CONST.SECID = I.SECID
WHERE D.DATE_ BETWEEN '1800-01-01'::date AND CURRENT_DATE()
```

### Alternative SQL 2:

So here I dropped the correlated sub-query's TOP 1 and replace with an outer WHERE, not as glamourous. But it might work. From there speed can be added once failure has be avoided.

```
create or replace table TABLE_DATE(DATE_ date);
create or replace table TABLE_CONST(STARTDATE date, ENDDATE date, code number, SECID number);
create or replace table TABLE_INFO(code number);
create or replace table TABLE_A(date_ date, SECID number, I_CODE number);
create or replace table TABLE_B(date_ date, I_CODE number);
create or replace table TABLE_I(SECID number);

SELECT *
FROM TABLE_DATE AS D
LEFT JOIN TABLE_CONST AS CONST
    ON CODE = 999
    AND D.DATE_ BETWEEN CONST.STARTDATE AND COALESCE(CONST.ENDDATE,LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE()))
LEFT JOIN TABLE_INFO AS M 
    ON CONST.CODE = M.CODE
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT *
        ,row_number() over (ORDER BY a.DATE_ DESC) AS RN
    FROM TABLE_A AS A
    WHERE SECID = CONST.SECID
    AND a.DATE_ <= D.DATE_
) AS SEC
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT *
        ,row_number() over (ORDER BY b.DATE_ DESC) AS RN
    FROM TABLE_B AS B 
    WHERE b.I_CODE = SEC.I_CODE 
    AND b.DATE_ <= D.DATE_
    ORDER BY b.DATE_ DESC
) XR
LEFT JOIN TABLE_I I ON CONST.SECID = I.SECID
WHERE D.DATE_ BETWEEN '1800-01-01'::date AND CURRENT_DATE()
and xr.rn = 1 AND sec.rn = 1
```

### Some data that triggers the problem:

```
WITH TABLE_DATE(DATE_) as (
    select * from values
    ('2022-04-01'::date),
    ('2022-03-01'::date),
    ('2022-01-01'::date)
), TABLE_CONST(STARTDATE, ENDDATE, code, SECID) as (
    select * from values
    ('2022-04-01'::date, '2022-04-01'::date, 997, 667),
    ('2022-03-01'::date, '2022-03-01'::date, 998, 668),
    ('2022-01-01'::date, '2022-01-01'::date, 999, 669)
), TABLE_INFO(code) as (
    select * from values
    (999),
    (998)
), TABLE_A(date_, SECID, I_CODE) as (
    select * from values
    ('2022-04-01'::date, 667, 767),
    ('2022-03-29'::date, 667, 767),
    ('2022-03-28'::date, 667, 767),
    ('2022-03-01'::date, 668, 768),
    ('2022-02-28'::date, 668, 768),
    ('2022-02-27'::date, 668, 768),
    ('2022-01-01'::date, 669, 769),
    ('2021-12-29'::date, 669, 769),
    ('2021-12-28'::date, 669, 769)
), TABLE_B(date_, I_CODE) as (
    select * from values
    ('2022-04-01'::date, 767),
    ('2022-03-29'::date, 767),
    ('2022-03-28'::date, 767),
    ('2022-03-01'::date, 768),
    ('2022-02-28'::date, 768),
    ('2022-02-27'::date, 768),
    ('2022-01-01'::date, 769),
    ('2021-12-29'::date, 769),
    ('2021-12-28'::date, 769)
), TABLE_I(SECID ) as (
    select * from values
    (999),
    (998)
)
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_DATE AS D
LEFT JOIN TABLE_CONST AS CONST
    ON CONST.CODE = 999
    AND D.DATE_ BETWEEN CONST.STARTDATE AND COALESCE(CONST.ENDDATE,LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE()))
LEFT JOIN TABLE_INFO AS M 
    ON CONST.CODE = M.CODE
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT A.*
        ,row_number() over (ORDER BY a.DATE_ DESC) AS RN
    FROM TABLE_A AS A
    WHERE A.SECID = CONST.SECID
    AND a.DATE_ <= D.DATE_
) AS SEC
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT B.*
        ,row_number() over (ORDER BY b.DATE_ DESC) AS RN
    FROM TABLE_B AS B 
    WHERE b.I_CODE = SEC.I_CODE 
    AND b.DATE_ <= D.DATE_
    ORDER BY b.DATE_ DESC
) XR
LEFT JOIN TABLE_I I ON CONST.SECID = I.SECID
WHERE D.DATE_ BETWEEN '1800-01-01'::date AND CURRENT_DATE()
and xr.rn = 1 AND sec.rn = 1;
```

now we are in luck, we have some data that triggers the problem, we can fix the problem..

### So now lets make some code that works:

So this removes the sub-queries, and goes for just plan old join, and then throws away heaps of rows at the end. It's rather gross, and I would tend to prefer to do this earlier in the processing chain. But "it compiles" is a plus...

```
WITH TABLE_DATE(DATE_) as (
    select * from values
    ('2022-04-01'::date),
    ('2022-03-01'::date),
    ('2022-01-01'::date)
), TABLE_CONST(STARTDATE, ENDDATE, code, SECID) as (
    select * from values
    ('2022-04-01'::date, '2022-04-01'::date, 999, 667),
    ('2022-03-01'::date, '2022-03-01'::date, 999, 668),
    ('2022-01-01'::date, '2022-01-01'::date, 999, 669)
), TABLE_INFO(code) as (
    select * from values
    (999),
    (998)
), TABLE_A(date_, SECID, I_CODE) as (
    select * from values
    ('2022-04-01'::date, 667, 767),
    ('2022-03-29'::date, 667, 767),
    ('2022-03-28'::date, 667, 767),
    ('2022-03-01'::date, 668, 768),
    ('2022-02-28'::date, 668, 768),
    ('2022-02-27'::date, 668, 768),
    ('2022-01-01'::date, 669, 769),
    ('2021-12-29'::date, 669, 769),
    ('2021-12-28'::date, 669, 769)
), TABLE_B(date_, I_CODE) as (
    select * from values
    ('2022-04-01'::date, 767),
    ('2022-03-29'::date, 767),
    ('2022-03-28'::date, 767),
    ('2022-03-01'::date, 768),
    ('2022-02-28'::date, 768),
    ('2022-02-27'::date, 768),
    ('2022-01-01'::date, 769),
    ('2021-12-29'::date, 769),
    ('2021-12-28'::date, 769)
), TABLE_I(SECID ) as (
    select * from values
    (669),
    (667)
)
SELECT 
    d.date_ as d_date
    ,CONST.STARTDATE as c_STARTDATE
    ,CONST.ENDDATE as c_ENDDATE
    ,CONST.code as c_code
    ,CONST.SECID as c_SECID
    ,m.code as m_code
    ,sec.date_ as s_date
    ,sec.secid as s_secid
    ,sec.i_code as s_i_code
    ,xr.date_ as xr_date
    ,xr.i_code as xr_icode
    ,i.*
FROM TABLE_DATE AS D
LEFT JOIN TABLE_CONST AS CONST
    ON CONST.CODE = 999
    AND D.DATE_ BETWEEN CONST.STARTDATE AND COALESCE(CONST.ENDDATE,LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE()))
LEFT JOIN TABLE_INFO AS M 
    ON CONST.CODE = M.CODE
LEFT JOIN TABLE_A AS SEC
    ON sec.SECID = CONST.SECID and sec.date_ <= D.DATE_ 
LEFT JOIN TABLE_B AS XR
    ON xr.I_CODE = SEC.I_CODE AND xr.DATE_ <= D.DATE_
LEFT JOIN TABLE_I I ON CONST.SECID = I.SECID
WHERE D.DATE_ BETWEEN '1800-01-01'::date AND CURRENT_DATE()
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by D.DATE_, CONST.SECID order by sec.date_ desc, xr.DATE_ DESC) = 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

### Lets give CTE's a Try:

Now I have pretended the CTE's I were using are full tables, the same main body can be written with those sub-queries written as incremental clean-up so the data does not explode too much. And also for simplicity also carry the used values forward. I would also try without carrying, and doing cleaner joins. But it all really depends on your data.

```
WITH CTE_A AS (
    SELECT     
        d.date_ as d_date
        ,CONST.STARTDATE as c_STARTDATE
        ,CONST.ENDDATE as c_ENDDATE
        ,CONST.code as c_code
        ,CONST.SECID as c_SECID
    FROM TABLE_DATE AS D
    LEFT JOIN TABLE_CONST AS CONST
        ON CONST.CODE = 999
        AND D.DATE_ BETWEEN CONST.STARTDATE AND COALESCE(CONST.ENDDATE,LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE()))
    WHERE D.DATE_ BETWEEN '1800-01-01'::date AND CURRENT_DATE()
), CTE_B AS (
    SELECT 
        x.d_date
        ,x.c_STARTDATE
        ,x.c_ENDDATE
        ,x.c_code
        ,x.c_SECID
        ,sec.date_ as s_date
        ,sec.secid as s_secid
        ,sec.i_code as s_i_code
    FROM CTE_A as x
    LEFT JOIN TABLE_A AS SEC
        ON sec.SECID = x.C_SECID and sec.date_ <= x.d_DATE
    QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by x.d_DATE, x.C_SECID order by sec.date_ desc) = 1
), CTE_C AS (
    SELECT 
        y.d_date
        ,y.c_STARTDATE
        ,y.c_ENDDATE
        ,y.c_code
        ,y.c_SECID
        ,y.s_date
        ,y.s_secid
        ,y.s_i_code
        ,xr.date_ as xr_date
        ,xr.i_code as xr_icode
    FROM CTE_B as y
    LEFT JOIN TABLE_B AS XR
    ON xr.I_CODE = y.s_i_code AND xr.DATE_ <= y.d_DATE
    QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by y.d_DATE, y.C_SECID order by xr.date_ desc) = 1
)
SELECT 
    z.d_date
    ,z.c_STARTDATE
    ,z.c_ENDDATE
    ,z.c_code
    ,z.c_SECID
    ,m.code as m_code
    ,z.s_date
    ,z.s_secid
    ,z.s_i_code
    ,z.xr_date
    ,z.xr_icode
    ,i.secid as i_secid
FROM CTE_C AS z
LEFT JOIN TABLE_INFO AS M 
    ON z.c_CODE = M.CODE
LEFT JOIN TABLE_I I ON z.C_SECID = I.SECID
ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: Really really appreciate you helping me again. I have tried this but it gave me another error “unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated”

Comment: this is because the shape of you data is making the corollate queries unresolvable for the compiler.

Comment: without knowing the shape of you data it's hard to avoid these, optimally. Also not knowing what is the answer you are trying to get. But given like last time you question is "WHY THIS ERROR" not "how to I get SQL/DATA I will not show you working to answer questions I will not tell you.

Comment: Really sorry  but I have really no idea  what I don’t know and I have been working on this for 2 days with no progression. Really thanks for the answer and apologies if I have offended you

Comment: Well the point when the first question didn't work for you, ether you could have "answered" because if remove the problem you had albeit another problem was behind it. Or you can have talked about the new problem you felt was still the same problem. And improved the question or data

Comment: Yes, you’re right, it was wrong and disrespectful of me to delete the original question and should have edited/improve on the original qns. Sorry about that and it will be something that I will not do again

Comment: I am still having the same error. Just to clarify, the cause of this error is the correlated sub query and in order for me to resolve the issue, I have to look back at how the data is structured and reformat the correlated sub-query to a non-correlated one??

Comment: The gist is sub-queries can be optimal is "small/medium" DB's But generally in a huge DB, the lack of index's due to the huge size, they are not performant.

Comment: I’m a bit confuse. Is this only for the case of snowflake? Because the original code was able to work in MS SQL.

Comment: Well if you had no indexes in MS your sub-queries would perfrom vary badly. Snowflake has no indexes, but they appear to be a free lunch which doesn't exist, so you just have to build filter/lookup tables if you want that magic, as a general rule.

Comment: So for the issue that I’m trying to resolve here, would using CTE help? I have seen several resources mentioned to use CTE. I have tried but it didn’t work (but it could also be me not constructing the CTE in the right way)

Comment: A CTE "mostly" is like folders in a filing cabernet. Helpful, but the metal draw can hold the paper in one pile or in folders... terrible metaphor..

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. I’ll take it back, try to process and digest it and see how it goes from there! Thanks!